# Update all the elements of JSON array nested in a JSON column (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have json column with data that looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo(mycol)
AS SELECT $${
    "a": [
        { "q": 5 },
        { "q": 8 },
        { "q": 10 }
    ]
}$$::jsonb;
```

I'd like to map over the elements in the array and add an extra property to get something like this:

```json
{
    a: [
        { q: 5, r: [] },
        { q: 8, r: [] },
        { q: 10, r: [] }
    ]
}
```

Any and all would be greatly appreciated.

PostgreSQL 9.6.6

Comment: If *all* your key names are stable, consider a relational design instead of the json column. Simpler queries, smaller, faster, cleaner.

Comment: If it was my choice I would

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked it out. Something like:

```sql
SELECT my_column::jsonb ||
    jsonb_build_object('a',
            (SELECT json_agg(a::jsonb || jsonb_build_object('r','[]'::jsonb))
            FROM jsonb_array_elements(my_column->'a') a)
    )
FROM my_table;
```

Though this might not be perfect since I'm translating to this example without testing.

Comment: You may find it faster to use jsonb_set

Answer (score 0):

Rather than building a new object,  you can use `jsonb_set`

```sql
SELECT jsonb_set(
  mycol,
  ARRAY['a'],
  jsonb_agg(x || '{"r":[]}'::jsonb),
  true
)
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(mycol->'a')
  AS t(x)
GROUP BY mycol;
```